Is it permissible to make clay sculptures of animate objects as long as you don't idolize them, and specifically use them for entertainment?
A little reference to this question: How can sculpting/drawing be Haram when Isa (PBUH) sculpted a bird?
In the past, these clay sculptures were made mainly for worship and creating idols, it was their 'intention'. What if my 'intention' of creating these clay sculptures was purely for entertainment? Like toys, decor pieces and whatnot? Doesn't intention usually, and mostly always, matter when an action is done? Is this halal in a way?
In the last comment of the question link I provided, does that link to anything mentioned here? I would really appreciate some insight as I am constantly in debate of this situation. Thank you.

Assalamualaikum warahmatullahi wabarakatuh,
This link is to answer your question:
https://islamqa.info/en/answers/98533/sculpting-with-clay-what-is-and-is-not-permissible
In summary, you cannot make animate objects using clay or anything else, including using the camera on your phone to take pictures of people. However, you can use clay to make inanimate objects like trees and other things without souls.
